# get day of month based on server timezone

Tags: php

I want to check the day of the month based on the current server timezone.

I have tried:

```
$timestamp = time();

if(date('j', $timestamp) === '8')
```

But date() was returning a 7 this morning when my server's time was showing as the 8th.  It appears that time() does not pick up the timezone.

I do not want to change the global default timezone nor specify a specific timezone in my code.  I want to pick up on the server time.

Comment: PHP's allowed to have a different timezone than the underlying server. Check the value of `date_default_timezone_get` and compare it to the server's setting.

Comment: It's returning UTC whilst my server time is UTC+10.  But I do not want to try to change the default php timezone as that might break something else.

Comment: Well, you can either change the servers's time, PHP's time, or you can use `date_default_timezone_set` everywhere. Up to you.

Comment: So ceejayoz, you are saying there is no way to do what I want?

Comment: I'm saying there are several ways to do what you want. I can't help it if you refuse them all.

Comment: Why don't you post as answer then ceejayoz.  There are no other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options:

- Adjust the PHP timezone setting in `php.ini` to match the underlying server.
- Adjust the underlying server's timezone to match PHP.
- Use `date_default_timezone_set` in your code to change the timezone, either across-the-board, or just when you need to work with dates (perhaps via a helper function).
- Manually add/subtract seconds from the value of `time()` when you use it.